# Database Insert and Delete with Stored Procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, stored-procedures, button

In my `.aspx` page, i have two textbox and one add button and one delete button.

I want simply, when entering data textboxes and click add button, adding to database with stored procedure.

When entering data textboxes and click delete button, delete from database with stored procedure.

How can I do that?

Simply I need 4 code part, `add_click()`, `delete_click()`, `sp_add`, `sp_delete`

How can I develop this 4 function?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You're asking for a lot of code for one answer...

Comment: Please also state your knowledge/experience and the areas of difficulty, since it's impossible to give you an answer when we don't know where to start. As things stand right now, the answer would have to be a tiny application.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since you're giving us any hint what your table(s) look like and what your textboxes will be, this is just a "template" like approach.

BTW: you should **not** prefix your stored procedures with `sp_` - that prefix is reserved for Microsoft.

**proc_delete**

Idea: you just pass in the primary key (usually an `ID` of some sort) to be deleted:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.proc_delete(@PrimaryKey INT)
AS
   DELETE FROM dbo.YourTable
   WHERE ID = @PrimaryKey
```

**proc_add**

You don't really tell us much about what you want to do ..... so here is one possibility

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.proc_add(@value1 VARCHAR(50), @value2 VARCHAR(50))
AS 
    INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable(Value1, Value2)
    VALUES(@value1, @value2)
```

From your ASP.NET code, you would have to do the following:

- create a `SqlConnection` to the database
- create a suitable `SqlCommand` to execute the command you want
- set up the parameters and fill their values
- execute the proc

So in the case of the `delete_click()`, you'd have something like:

```
public void delete_click()
{
    using(SqlConnection _con = new SqlConnection(-your-connection-string-here-))
    using(SqlCommand _cmdDelete = new SqlCommand(_con, "dbo.proc_delete"))
    {
        _cmdDelete.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // add parameter
        _cmdDelete.Parameters.Add("@PrimaryKey", SqlDbType.Int);
        _cmdDelete.Parameters["@PrimaryKey"].Value = (your key value here);

        // open connection, execute command, close connection
        _con.Open();
        _cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
        _con.Close();
    }
}
```

That would be the rough outline of how to do it - I'll leave the `add_click()` up to you!